# In drupal event calendar how to show events in popup

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I have a drupal event calendar, When I click on an event it shows event details in a new page, How to show event details in a popup?

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Calendar Popup module (part of the [Calendar module](http://drupal.org/project/calendar)).

[image: Calendar Popup]

Comment: i have enabled it's working for calendar module. it's not working for event calendar

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a hidden fields and use simple jQuery to show them on hover.